# Why isn't my string being displayed in the window?

Tags: java, string, swing, window, jframe

I am trying to create a simple application that shows a red circle that when clicked displays different messages under it. I believe that this part of the code:

```
g.drawString("DO NOT PRESS", 100, 100);
```

is coded correctly but no text is displayed on the window that opens. Here is the full code so far:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BigRedButton extends JFrame {

    public BigRedButton() {

        setTitle("Big Red Button");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

    public void graphics(Graphics g) {

        g.drawString("DO NOT PRESS", 100, 100);
}
    public static void main(String[] args){

        new BigRedButton();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Add `@Override` notation to methods that should change behavior, to check that the signature is correct. 2) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.

Answer (score 4):

1. There is no such method `graphics` in `JFrame`, so nothing is calling it.
2. You should avoid painting directly to top level containers, apart from everthing else, they're not double buffered and will flicker when painted.  You should, instead, create a custom component (extending from something like `JPanel`) and override it's `paintComponent` method.
3. You should take the time to read through [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Also, while your reading up, you should have a read through [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

**Amendment**

As pointed out by Andrew, you should use the `@Override` annotation to ensure that the method you think you are overriding is actually the method being overridden in the first place.  This would stop the program from being compiled and save lots of lost time trying to figure out why things aren't working the way you expect them.

Comment: Also add `@Override` notation to methods that should change behavior, to check that the signature is correct.